# Default FileField names for Django files

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    unique_hash = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='source',blank=True,verbose_name="HTML Content File")
```

I would like to be able to set the content filename to default to a callable, but I don't see any way to have the callable reference unique_hash (or vice versa).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that callable should generate filename, I'm not aware of that.

You can, however, use custom storage (see docs, subclass `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`) that will provide custom algorithm for filename generation.

Comment: callable can generate a filename with default=callable

Comment: Darn, sorry, was not reading thoroughly. AFAIK, usual way to do defaults for fields as unqiue_hash is to overwrite `save()` method.